# Better way to deploy to Windows Mobile Device

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

I have been working on a Windows Mobile app for a little while now (havnt done much work with mobile before) and i have been having a problem when deploying to my mobile, at the moment i can only run the application once then if i want to run it again i have to do a soft reset.

Maybe im deploying wrong? (pretty sure i am actually, im pretty much just copying the .exe file across and running it.)

What is a better way for me to deploy my application so that it can run more than once per reset?
At the moment when i try to run it for the 2nd time on my mobile nothing at all happens (yet it works fine using the Windows Mobile 6.1 emulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAB files are the preferred way to deploy Windows Mobile applications. Check out this MSDN article:

[CAB Files for Delivering Windows Mobile Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158712.aspx)

I've had some success with putting a CAB file on a web server and simply http'ing to it to download and install the CAB.

Comment: How do i actually create the cab file?

Comment: Read the first paragraph of the article I linked to! It tells you how and links you to a walkthrough!

Comment: lol how did i miss that? Thanks for you help but im still having the issue where i can only run it once pre reset...

Comment: What stops you from running your program a second time before you reset? Is there an error message? Maybe add it to your question.

Comment: Nah no error or anything, pretty much just donent run, i click the shortcut and it just doesnt do anything. think it could be something to do with my application?

Comment: Yeah I reckon it's your app. Does it run multiple times if you run it on the device via Visual Studio? If not, maybe you could debug it.